# Java - Input Verifier

Tags: java, validation, inputverifier

I was just creating this specific but I was a little confused on documenting this. Am just stuck on explaining what the last couple of lines do :

```
class MyVerifier extends InputVerifier {

public boolean verify(JComponent input) {

  if (input==id) {
    return validId();

}

 else if (input==name) {
     return validName();

 }

 return false;
}

    public boolean validId() {
      boolean status;
      String theID = id.getText();
      Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{8}");
      Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theID);
      if (matcher.matches()) {
          status = true;
      }
      else {
          status = false;
      }
       return status;
    }
    public boolean validName() {
       boolean status;
       String theName = name.getText();
       Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("[A-za-z0-9 ]+");
       Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(theName);
       if (matcher.matches()) {
           status = true;
       }
       else {
           status = false;
       }
       return status;
    }
}
```

---

COULD YOU EXPLAIN THESE SPECIFIC LINES HERE ONE BY ONE ?

```
/**
 * @param  o    the object corresponding to the user's selection
 */
@Override
public void tell(Object o) { -- Where has this come from ?
    deptCode.setText(o.toString());
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getSource() == submit) {
        MyVerifier test = new MyVerifier();

        if (Staff.getStaff(id.getText()) == null && test.verify(id) &&
                test.verify(name)) {
            System.out.println("YAY");-- What is this doing
        }
        else if (!(Staff.getStaff(id.getText()) == null)) {
            String errorMessage = "ID EXISTS: " + Staff.getStaff(id.getText()).toString(); -- What is this doing

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(theFrame, errorMessage, "Error",
                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);-- What is this doing
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Woops.");
        }
    }

    else if (e.getSource() == clear) {
        id.setText(null);
        deptCode.setText(null);
        name.setText(null);
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Registration test = new Registration();
}
}
```

Comment: If you wrote them yourself how come you don't know what they mean? Why did you write them?

Comment: @MaurícioLinhares Aliens

Comment: `System.out.println("YAY");`; do we really need to explain what that's doing?

Comment: What is your actual question?

Comment: Yeah I'm gonna go ahead and say if you can't explain this then you didn't write it..  I also don't think anyone can tell you what exactly this does without the full context of the program as it looks like there are some graphics involved.

Comment: `tell` either comes from the parent object or some `interface` which has begin implemented by your class (or abstract parent class)

Answer (score 0):

Now that you understand what you're trying to accomplish with this program, start from a clean slate (using your first attempt as an example if necessary).  It's often easier to start over than to fix a program.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your `public void tell(Object o)` method is setting a String with the value of the object passed. Because you haven't shown us what your using it for, though, it's impossible for us to know for sure. On the other hand, your other problems are fairly clear:

`System.out.println("YAY");`

It appears that `Staff.getStaff(id.getText)` is checking either a String or a text file for a list of names and id's. This statement prints "YAY" only if there hasn't previously been created a staff member with the provided `id` and `name`. But since you also haven't shown us where those variables are, this is only my best guess.

`JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(theFrame, errorMessage, "Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);`

This displays a `JOptionPane` warning message if there is already a staff member with the given `id` or `name`. Obviously, you cannot create an account that someone else has, so this `JOptionPane` displays an error message if this is, indeed, the case.